# Skip XML headers when writing through iteration in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am very new to C# so I apologise in advance if this question is easily answered... 
I have a program that creates some objects and writes their properties to a text file (.txt). 
From this text file, it reads every other line as it contains an ID - and creates a bunch of new objects with those IDs.

I am supposed to take these new objects, add them to a `List`, and write them to an XML file. Now, considering that I have given up trying to add these objects (and each of their individual properties) to a `List` as I can't make it work, I am trying to just get these objects and write them into the XML.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 2)
    {

      //Functions of IAnimal take int values so the string needs to be converted.
      int nooID = Convert.ToInt32(animalist[i]);

      //Create a new animal for every iteration and assign it the new ID/name.
      IAnimal nooanimal = new IAnimal();
      nooanimal.setID(nooID);
      nooanimal.setname(nooID);

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(nooanimal.GetType());

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText("animalist.xml"))
{
        serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, nooanimal);
}
}
```

This works, that is, it creates the XML file and it contains all of the elements that it should contain. However, it presents itself like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Animal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>300</ID>
  <Name>Animal_300</Name>
</Animal><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Animal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>301</ID>
  <Name>Animal_301</Name>
</Animal>
```

And I can't open it properly because the header is repeated for each object. 
I tried creating the file before the `for` hoping that would write the headers and that I could just fill it through the iteration, but the file is empty.
Is there something wrong in the way I am writing to the file, or perhaps in how I have set up the class in question for serialisation? 
Thanks!

Comment: Controlling serialization using attributes may be heplful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid XML file should contain only one root element. Though if you remove repeated header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` your XML file will still be invalid.
Try this:

```
List<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i += 2)
{

  //Functions of IAnimal take int values so the string needs to be converted.
  int nooID = Convert.ToInt32(animalist[i]);

  //Create a new animal for every iteration and assign it the new ID/name.
  IAnimal nooanimal = new IAnimal();
  nooanimal.setID(nooID);
  nooanimal.setname(nooID);
  animals.Add(nooanimal);
}

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = 
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IAnimal>));

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText("animalist.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, animals);
}
```

Comment: That solves both my problems! Thank you! I don't understand why it didn't work when I tried to add each `nooanimal` to `List<IAnimal>` (Getting a count of the list always returned 1)... But I can investigate now :) Does this code not repeat the header because it writes the `List` rather than go through each iteration along with the objects?

Comment: @Nicholas `Does this code not repeat the header because it writes the List rather than go through each iteration along with the objects?` Yes, it is. When you serialize some data into XML, there will be always one topmost element, that will be hold within all data. In your case that object is `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom `XmlWriterSettings`
2. Set  the property [OmitXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true`
3. Create an `XmlWriter` with those settings, and serialize into that.